# How to configure Spring Security + OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building a REST Application using Spring Security + OAuth2.

If i use

```
curl -u clientapp:123456 -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept:application/json" -d "username=admin&password=123456&grant_type=password"
```

I do not get the response

But if i add the application contextpath i am able to.

```
curl -u clientapp:123456 -X POST http://localhost:8080/demoproject/oauth/token -H "Accept:application/json" -d "username=admin&password=123456&grant_type=password"
```

Also getting success response

```
{"access_token":"dc86814f-94a5-43b7-9e8d-73b143b28c64","token_type":"bearer","re
fresh_token":"09c7e31e-b8e7-4bf2-a839-9e8d4702b822","expires_in":2837,"scope":"r
ead write"}
```

But when use the access token to request a secured API, I'm getting login page as response because of Spring Security Configuration.

Here is my Configration:

WebMvcInitializer.java

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { 
                WebConfig.class, 
                WebSecurityConfiguration.class, 
                Oauth2ServerConfiguration.AuthConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration .java

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

         @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return encoder;
        }

        @Override
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER"); 
            //super.configure(http);
        }
    }
```

WebConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.demo.springoauth")  
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return viewResolver;
        }


        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        } 
    }
```

SecurityInitializer.java

```
 import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;  
            public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

            }
```

Oauth2ServerConfiguration.java

```
  @Configuration
    public class Oauth2ServerConfiguration {

        private static final String SERVER_RESOURCE_ID = "oauthdemo";

        private static InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Configuration
        @EnableResourceServer
        protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception { 
                resources.resourceId(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID);
            }

            @Override
            @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


                http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**" , "/noauth/**" , "/api/r/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/w/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER"); 


}
        }



        @Configuration
        @EnableAuthorizationServer
        protected static class AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
            private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

            @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
                oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
                endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients.inMemory().withClient("clientapp").authorizedGrantTypes("password","client_credentials", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "ROLE_USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write").resourceIds(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID).secret("123456").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
            }

            @Bean
            @Primary
            public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
                DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
                tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
                tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
                return tokenServices;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>springoauth</artifactId>
    <name>springoauth</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>

        <spring.security.oauth2.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.oauth2.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>


    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>springoauth</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/messages*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/messages*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there something in spring configuration that I'm doing wrong?